# How to show progress of `stack haddock`?

Tags: haskell-stack, haddock, haskell-src-exts

Ran

```
stack haddock haskell-src-exts
```

I get:

```
haskell-src-exts-1.20.3: configure
haskell-src-exts-1.20.3: build
haskell-src-exts-1.20.3: haddock
```

And I've been waiting around for an hour but it still hasn't finished.

Adding

```
--haddock-arguments --verbosity=3
```

doesn't seem to change anything.

It would be really nice to have some sort of progress indicator so I can know if it's stuck or just slow.

---

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.9.1, Git revision f9d0042c141660e1d38f797e1d426be4a99b2a3c (6168 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.0
```