# What does `stack haddock --skip <pkgname>` do?

Tags: haskell-stack, haddock, haskell-src-exts

After being unable to run `stack haddock` on my project because one package causes it to hang (see [How to show progress of `stack haddock`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52893750/403875) ) I tried to *skip* that package with

```
stack haddock --skip haskell-src-exts
```

But it still tries to haddock `haskell-src-exts` anyway (and hangs). What is `--skip` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--skip` was introduced in stack 1.6.1 to avoid building a specific component of a project. A component corresponded to a test suite, an executable or a benchmark suite. As backpack support is implemented, this will have to include libraries, too.

From `stack build --help`

> --skip ARG               Skip given component, can be specified multiple times

The docs go into more detail.

> - `--skip`, to skip building components of a local package. It allows
>     you to skip test suites and benchmark without specifying other components
>     (e.g. `stack test --skip long-test-suite` will run the tests without the
>     `long-test-suite` test suite). Be aware that skipping executables won't work
>     the first time the package is built due to 
>     [an issue in cabal](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3229).
>     This option can be specified multiple times to skip multiple components.

For example, a package `my-package` might have a library, an executable `my-executable`, and two test suites (`unit-tests` and `integration-tests`). To build and run tests, you may run `stack test`. Adding `--skip integration-tests` will cause the `integration-tests` component not to be built (nor run).

Unfortunately, the current version of stack (1.9 branch) does not support skipping haddock for individual dependencies, though there is something like this due in the near future. I encountered this exact same problem (with haskell-src-exts). For now, I suggest skipping all haddock dependencies (`--no-haddock-deps`).

You may wish to invoke haddock with `stack exec -- haddock` if you wish to pass arguments to haddock which do not work with the stack flag `--haddock-arguments`.

Comment: Thank you. So to be clear, this skips executable/test targets etc? but won't skip anything which is a dependency of whatever you're trying to build?

Comment: That is correct. The one subtlety concerns dependencies of these skipped targets; I'll investigate.